# How to preserve spaces in svg text

Tags: svg, snap.svg

To preserve spaces in a textelement of svg, one should use 'xml:space="preserve"' as an attribute of the text [(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7k5sj/5/). However, it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
    // init snap
    var svgElement=document.getElementById("mainSvgId");
    var s = Snap(svgElement).attr({height: 300, width: 300});

    // greate group with rectanle
    var parentGroup=s.g().attr({id: "parent"});
    var rect1 = s.rect(0, 0, 200, 200).attr({fill: "#bada55"});
    parentGroup.add(rect1);

    // add text with preserve attribute
    var text = s.text(0, 20, "   text1    text2");
    text.node.setAttribute("xml:space", "preserve");
    parentGroup.add(text);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to properly create the attribute in the xml namespace for which you need setAttributeNS rather than setAttribute

```
text.node.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "xml:space", "preserve");
```

Comment: This is apparently [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xml:space). You're meant to use [CSS whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) now.

Comment: @Timmmm original solution by Robert works. Does CSS `whitespace: pre` has the same behavior as xml:space attribute?